# Xcode -User Interface Inspector Position X and Position Y values?

Tags: xcode, frame, bounds, cgrect, cgpoint

Using the Xcode User Interface Inspector what are the `Position x` and `Position y` values?

If you look at my picture, the frame I'm inspecting starts at `CGPoint` 0,0 and it's bounds are 0,0.

What does the 207 and 327.222 correspond to?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that is the view's backing `layer` position. Since positions of `CALayers` are referring to their center, the values are practically half of the size you get on the inspector (414 / 2 = 207 & 654.67 / 2 ≃ 327). My guess is based on the `Z Position` which is also a property of a layer.

**EDIT:** After some search at Apple's documentation, this property is described as ["Position in the parent"](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev4dfdedb7a) (click on "View debugger size inspector") which is quite confusing since this is (when talking about views) the frame's origin.

Comment: I just multiplied them by 2. You are correct. Thanks